# Direct Memory Mapping to DIMM

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, x86-64

Assume you have 2 DIMMs inserted into an `Intel x86-64` motherboard. All memory interleaving (bank and channel) is disabled.

What I am trying to do is reserve the physical memory space of one of those DIMMs from the `Linux kernel` (version `4.11.11`) and expose that physical (reserved) memory space for an application. The DIMMs will *not* be moved in the memory channels. How would I got about doing this? What would the process be? I am new to kernel development and could use guidance.

What I have found so far:

1. To reserve memory from the Linux kernel you can specify the `memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]` boot parameter. This parameter marks specific memory as a reserved region of memory from ss to ss+nn.
2. *[mmap](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap)* can be used to establish a mapping between the address space of a process at an address *pa* for *len* bytes to the memory object represented by the file descriptor *fildes* at offset *off* for *len* bytes.

After the memory is reserved, I'm assuming that some character device driver is needed to expose the reserved memory to the user space application? Thoughts?

---

Update

It should also be noted that the DIMM that needs to be reserved will be in it's own dedicated memory channel and no bank or channel interleaving will be enabled.

Comment: I don't see how the DIMM part fit into the whole picture. Anyway, wouldn't something like `/dev/mem` do? I don't know if the reserved memory would be mapped by such device.

Comment: @MargaretBloom What is unclear about the DIMM? I am trying to reserve all of the memory on one of the DIMMs from use by the kernel. Is that clear? `/dev/mem` represents all of memory available for use by the kernel, and therefore is not necessarily representative of what I need.

Comment: You could expose it via a new flag for `mmap`, i.e. define a `MAP_RESERVED_DIMM`, if there are any unused bits in the flag arg.  HugeTLBFS is another model: a special filesystem that you can map files on to get mappings with something special about the backing memory.  I'm not an expert on Linux internals (just an interested amateur), but your idea of a char or block device might work, too.  Especially if you only plan to have one user-space process at a time using it, otherwise how do you let them figure out which parts are already mapped?

Comment: I'm not sure there's very good support for discovering how physical addresses map to DIMMs.  Usually the BIOS configures that, and some BIOSes (especially servers) will let you choose the interleave parameters.  IDK what the granularity typically is; if it's less than 2MiB, you won't be able to use hugepages, and that's probably worse than whatever you hope to gain from this.

Comment: **What exactly do you hope to gain here?**  Some kind of bandwidth guarantee?  But a single DIMM might be sharing a channel with other DIMMs, and there are a lot of shared resources in the memory controller in the CPU.)  Please explain in more detail, so we can help you figure out if this is an X Y problem (e.g. maybe there's a better way to get whatever performance behaviour you're looking for.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the comments. I added some updates. Memory bank and channel interleaving will be disabled in the server platform, and the DIMM that must be reserved will be in its own dedicated channel. No other DIMMs will be present in the memory channel.

I am experimenting with some prefetch mechanisms and bandwidth is my target.

Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good reason for wanting this, but I'm not sure how well it will work.  Hardware prefetch doesn't take memory channels into account, just how busy the pipe is between L2 and L3, or whatever.  So if it's full of stores to the other channel, prefetch to the channel you're testing might not happen.  (OTOH, most of the prefetch hardware in Intel CPUs is in L2, which is private per-core.  I'm not sure how much impact traffic from other cores has on throttling prefetches.)  It would be a lot easier to just test on a mostly-idle system, if you can arrange that.

Comment: Software-prefetch instructions may also be discarded when memory is already busy with demand misses and write-back; it's not just HW prefetch that's affected.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand that it probably won't lead to *better* bandwidth than what is currently possible. It is for experimental research to test out some alternatives. I don't expect to beat out current bandwidth capabilities.

Comment: @Jonathan: right, but my point was that this won't necessarily isolate you from unrelated loads from other CPU cores.  So your data might still be noisy in some ways if the whole machine isn't idle.  But it could help simplify by removing the benefits of interleaving.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the clarification. So getting back to my original question, *how* would one go about reserving the memory associated with that DIMM from the Linux kernel? What's the best method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Mapping `/dev/mem` is the simple way. I have done this before. The `mmap` implement from [kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/char/mem.c?h=v4.13.4):

```
static int mmap_mem(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    size_t size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    phys_addr_t offset = (phys_addr_t)vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;

    /* It's illegal to wrap around the end of the physical address space. */
    if (offset + (phys_addr_t)size - 1 < offset)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!valid_mmap_phys_addr_range(vma->vm_pgoff, size))
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!private_mapping_ok(vma))
        return -ENOSYS;

    if (!range_is_allowed(vma->vm_pgoff, size))
        return -EPERM;

    if (!phys_mem_access_prot_allowed(file, vma->vm_pgoff, size,
                        &vma->vm_page_prot))
        return -EINVAL;

    vma->vm_page_prot = phys_mem_access_prot(file, vma->vm_pgoff,
                         size,
                         vma->vm_page_prot);

    vma->vm_ops = &mmap_mem_ops;

    /* Remap-pfn-range will mark the range VM_IO */
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma,
                vma->vm_start,
                vma->vm_pgoff,
                size,
                vma->vm_page_prot)) {
        return -EAGAIN;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only thing you may need to modify is `valid_mmap_phys_addr_range(vma->vm_pgoff, size)`. Or you can write your own version of `/dev/mem` driver.

Comment: But this doesn't **allocate / reserve** those regions of physical memory to stop them from being used for anything else, does it?  And what are the implications of having it mapped as `VM_IO`, as that comment indicates?  mmap(/dev/mem) might well be a useful part of a complete answer, but I didn't think this part was the hard part.

Comment: Use `mem=xx` cmdline for kernel to use only part of memory. For example, passing `mem=4G` will make kernel only use memory below 4G, then you can use modified `/dev/mem` driver to mmap memory above 4G.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and should work for the OP's setup with no interleaving.  Are you sure `/dev/mem` can still access memory outside the range that the rest of the kernel thinks exists?

Comment: No, you can't directly use `/dev/mem` to achieve your goal. As I posted, you should do some modification about the address checking.